# How to capture the last amount in the row by REGEX

Tags: regex

I'm worning on the REGEX pattern to capture the last amount in the row. String looks like:

```
Ben
1x 1.32 1.32 OK

Mark
3x 0.50 1.50 FAIL

Johny
2x 1.20 2.40 OK
```

I can't write pattern to capture the last amount. The problem is "OK" and "FAIL" strings after the last amount. I don't know how to handle them by REGEX.

[image]

The three dots are just temporary solution to show you how it should works - it should also capture 1.50 amount too.

Please take a look:
https://regex101.com/r/vY6hI2/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?:OK|FAIL)$
```

It'll work for both decimal and integral values, because of the `(?:\.\d+)?` element, which makes the decimal point and trailing number optional. The number you want is in capture group 1.

[Demo on Regex101 (based on comment)](https://regex101.com/r/vY6hI2/4)